# Why does the following code compile using clang but not gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, unordered-map

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

struct tree_node {
  // tree_node() : attrib_val{"null"} {}
  std::unordered_map<std::string, tree_node> child;
};
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles just fine on my mac with clang:

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
$
```

On my linux machine, with gcc 9.1.0, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/ios:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, tree_node>’:
/usr/um/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/ext/aligned_buffer.h:91:28:   required from ‘struct __gnu_cxx::__aligned_buffer<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, tree_node> >’
/usr/um/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:233:43:   required from ‘struct std::__detail::_Hash_node_value_base<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, tree_node> >’
/usr/um/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:264:12:   required from ‘struct std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, tree_node>, true>’
/usr/um/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:2016:13:   required from ‘struct std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, tree_node>, true> > >’
/usr/um/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/hashtable.h:173:11:   required from ‘class std::_Hashtable<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, tree_node>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, tree_node> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >’
/usr/um/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/unordered_map.h:105:18:   required from ‘class std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, tree_node>’
test.cpp:7:46:   required from here
/usr/um/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:215:11: error: ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second’ has incomplete type
  215 |       _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
      |           ^~~~~~
test.cpp:5:8: note: forward declaration of ‘struct tree_node’
    5 | struct tree_node {
```

It doesn't like the `tree_node` as a value in `unordered_map` for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure this compiles on clang? It shouldn't since `tree_node` is an incomplete type when declaring `child`

Comment: It [doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/dfEdGb) compile on clang 10.0.

Comment: @cigien Yes. I just edited the OP with my terminal outputs.

Comment: @cigien Also, I wasn't aware that the incomplete type poses an issue. I've done this several times in other code as well, and don't recall seeing unexpected behavior.

Comment: Did you try some other standards?   If you man gcc there are 7 or 8 you can try.  It is very flexible.

Comment: @cigien It's probably not "it shouldn't compile," and more likely "it's undefined behavior."

Comment: This is not actually allowed. You can only use incomplete types as pointers, and in a few other contexts (basically where the size of the type is not needed). I'm pretty sure `unordered_map` is not one of them.

Comment: @HTNW Yes, that might be the case.

Comment: @JaMiT Ha, I was just asking myself this question, and couldn't answer it, so just asked a question :)

Comment: @JaMiT besides, OP is compiling with c++11.

Comment: Hates it in C++17, too. https://godbolt.org/z/H_wX4P

Comment: I think this is not added to map, even in c++17. Compilers used to not complain though.

Comment: `map` is cool with tthis. Since the main complaint is down it `std::pair`, `map`'s the first thing I checked.

Comment: It would seem vector worked before c++17 as well, but I'm pretty sure it was not supposed to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is undefined behavior, by [`[res.on.functions]/2.5`](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.functions#2.5):

> [The effects are undefined if] an incomplete type ([basic.types]) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component or evaluating a concept, unless specifically allowed for that component.

This is an annoying case where I basically have to prove a negative for this answer to be valid, but I find no place in the standard that mentions an exception that allows you to use an incomplete type in a `std::map`. Therefore, this program can do anything. In particular, though Clang compiles it now, it may stop working at any point in the future, and there's also a chance that the compiled code `map` specialization *doesn't work properly*. *Certain* containers, especially `std::vector`, have a clause that allows them to be instantiated at incomplete types under the right conditions. But this case is undefined behavior, and so compilers have no obligation to warn you or error. Change your program somehow to avoid this. I believe the following would be legal, without forcing you to store too many extra pointers.

```
struct tree_node {
  std::unique_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::string, tree_node>> child;
};
```

`std::unique_ptr` is an exception to the general no-go rule—it's OK to instantiate it at an incomplete type (but some of its members aren't as lax). I believe that this means that `std::unordered_map<std::string, tree_node>` is not required to be complete at the point in the definition of `tree_node` where the specialization of `std::unique_ptr` is required to be complete, and so the `std::unordered_map` specialization is not triggered and UB is avoided since `tree_node` is not required to be complete. Note that you can still write constructors, functions, a destructor, etc. without worry, since all of those definitions are implicitly moved out of and after the class definition, and `tree_node` becomes complete after the class definition ends.

Comment: Yeah, you were right, it's UB in this case. Nice answer :)

Comment: What is the advantage to making `child` a `unique_ptr` instead of the second value of child a `unique_ptr`, i.e., std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<tree_node>>> child? Not sure if this question is answerable without more information on what I am doing with this struct.

Comment: Honestly, a guess. An `unordered_map` already stores all of its data on the heap, behind a pointer. Making `tree_node` the value type means that it can store the `tree_node`s directly in the map structure, instead of having to go through more indirection. This shouldn't be entirely offset by the "initial" pointer added at the top of the structure. E.g. if you do a loop over the `map`, my suggestion hopefully means you only have to dereference an "extraneous" `unique_ptr` once, while your suggestion definitely means you have to dereference it for every single element.

Comment: Also, I suppose the interface is nicer. In particular, `*child` is a `std::unordered_map<std::string, node_type>` lvalue, which is conceptually the goal. Putting the pointers inside makes that "impossible".

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
struct tree_node {
  // tree_node() : attrib_val{"null"} {}
  std::unordered_map<std::string, tree_node> child;
};
```

To:

```
struct tree_node {
  // tree_node() : attrib_val{"null"} {}
  std::unordered_map<std::string, tree_node *> child;
};
```

Makes the compilation problem go away.   Whether it has any reflection on what you wanted?

Comment: This is a simple type forwarding , not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: The OP is asking why clang compiles the code and g++ doesn't.  The change above permits both to compile.  The underlying problem is likely that the map implementation is different between the systems; as is evidenced by installing clang on linux, and noting it has the same problems ( if a slightly less psychotic error avalanche ).

Comment: That is, the macos implementation resolves to a structure within tree_node which does not require the definition of tree_node (ie. uses pointers) ; thus this can compile; whereas the gnu/linux one requires a resolved structure.  It isn't forwarding; just that pointer types do not require structure definitions; just tags.