# C++17 forward declarations of custom structures in not working with custom Hash maps

Tags: c++, c++17

This is little frustrating me at this point, but I am not sure what am I doing wrong. My code is not compiling for using a hashmap with a custom hash function, which I think should be just okay to compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Key;
struct THash;
struct TEqual;

class Cache {
private:
    uint64_t capacity;
    uint64_t time_ticker;
    std::unordered_map<Key, int32_t, THash, TEqual> map_keys;
    std::priority_queue<Key> lru_min_heap;

    void RehashPriorityQueue()
    {
        lru_min_heap = std::priority_queue<Key>(); 
        for (auto &&iter : map_keys) lru_min_heap.emplace(iter.first); 
    }

public:
    Cache(const uint64_t cache_size=1) : capacity(cache_size), time_ticker(0) {}
    ~Cache(){}
    void Set(int32_t key, int32_t value) {
        time_ticker++;

        auto _key = Key(key, time_ticker);
        auto find_key = map_keys.find(_key);

        if(capacity) capacity--;
        else
        {
            auto lru = lru_min_heap.top(); lru_min_heap.pop();
            auto find_key_lru = map_keys.find(lru);
            if(find_key_lru != map_keys.end()) map_keys.erase(find_key_lru);
        }

        if(find_key != map_keys.end()) 
        {
            map_keys.erase(find_key);
            RehashPriorityQueue();
        }

        map_keys.emplace(_key, value);
        lru_min_heap.emplace(_key);
    }
    int32_t Get(int32_t key) {
        time_ticker++;
        int ret = 0;

        auto _key = Key(key, time_ticker);
        auto find_key = map_keys.find(_key);
        if(find_key != map_keys.end()) {
            ret = find_key->second;
            map_keys.erase(find_key);
            RehashPriorityQueue();
            map_keys.emplace(_key, ret);
            lru_min_heap.emplace(_key);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"None ";
        }

        return ret;
    }
};

struct Key {
    int32_t id; 
    uint64_t weightage;
    Key(int32_t id, uint64_t weightage=1) : id(id), weightage(weightage) {};
    bool operator<(const Key &other) const { return weightage > other.weightage;}
    size_t operator()(const Key& tr) const {
        return std::hash<int32_t>()(tr.id);
    }
};

struct THash {
    size_t operator()(const Key& tr) const {
        return std::hash<int32_t>()(tr.id);
    }
};

struct TEqual {
    bool operator()(const Key& tr1, const Key& tr2) const {
        if (tr1.id == tr2.id) return true;
        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Cache cache(2);
    cache.Set(3, 3);
    std::cout<<cache.Get(3)<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

compiler error:

```
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/hashtable.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/unordered_map:47,
                 from 3:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In instantiation of 'struct std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash>':
/usr/include/c++/4.9/type_traits:134:12:   required from 'struct std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> >'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/type_traits:145:38:   required from 'struct std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:100:66:   required from 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>'
13:53:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:85:33: error: no match for call to '(const THash) (const Key&)'
  noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))>
                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >':
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:100:66:   required from 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>'
13:53:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/type_traits:145:38: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> >'
     : public integral_constant<bool, !_Pp::value>
                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/unordered_map:48:0,
                 from 3:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h: In instantiation of 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>':
13:53:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:100:66: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef __umap_hashtable<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>  _Hashtable;
                                                                  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:107:45: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::key_type key_type;
                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:108:47: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::value_type value_type;
                                               ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:109:48: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::mapped_type mapped_type;
                                                ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:110:43: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::hasher hasher;
                                           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:111:46: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::key_equal key_equal;
                                              ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:112:51: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::allocator_type allocator_type;
                                                   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:117:45: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::pointer  pointer;
                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:118:50: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::const_pointer const_pointer;
                                                  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:119:47: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::reference  reference;
                                               ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:120:52: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::const_reference const_reference;
                                                    ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:121:46: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::iterator  iterator;
                                              ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:122:51: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::const_iterator const_iterator;
                                                   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:123:51: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::local_iterator local_iterator;
                                                   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:124:57: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::const_local_iterator const_local_iterator;
                                                         ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:125:47: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::size_type  size_type;
                                               ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:126:52: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::difference_type difference_type;
                                                    ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:242:7: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       operator=(initializer_list<value_type> __l)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:340:2: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
  emplace(_Args&&... __args)
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:392:7: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       insert(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:399:2: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
  insert(_Pair&& __x)
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:459:7: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       insert(initializer_list<value_type> __l)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:604:7: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       equal_range(const key_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:608:7: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<THash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Key, THash> > >'
       equal_range(const key_type& __x) const
       ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of 'struct std::pair<const Key, int>':
19:28:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h:101:11: error: 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::first' has incomplete type
       _T1 first;                 /// @c first is a copy of the first object
           ^
5:8: error: forward declaration of 'const struct Key'
 In member function 'void Cache::RehashPriorityQueue()':
19:28: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>&)'
19:28: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/initializer_list:89:5: note: template<class _Tp> constexpr const _Tp* std::begin(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)
     begin(initializer_list<_Tp> __ils) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/initializer_list:89:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
19:28: note:   'std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' is not derived from 'std::initializer_list<_Tp>'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:87:5: note: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> _Tp* std::begin(_Tp (&)[_Nm])
     begin(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:87:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
19:28: note:   mismatched types '_Tp [_Nm]' and 'std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:58:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(const _Container&)
     begin(const _Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.begin())
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:58:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(const _Container&) [with _Container = std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>]':
19:28:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:58:5: error: 'const class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'begin'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:48:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(_Container&)
     begin(_Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.begin())
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:48:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(_Container&) [with _Container = std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>]':
19:28:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:48:5: error: 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'begin'
19:28: error: no matching function for call to 'end(std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>&)'
19:28: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/initializer_list:99:5: note: template<class _Tp> constexpr const _Tp* std::end(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)
     end(initializer_list<_Tp> __ils) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/initializer_list:99:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
19:28: note:   'std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' is not derived from 'std::initializer_list<_Tp>'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> _Tp* std::end(_Tp (&)[_Nm])
     end(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
19:28: note:   mismatched types '_Tp [_Nm]' and 'std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:78:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(const _Container&)
     end(const _Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.end())
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:78:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(const _Container&) [with _Container = std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>]':
19:28:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:78:5: error: 'const class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'end'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:68:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(_Container&)
     end(_Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.end())
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:68:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(_Container&) [with _Container = std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>]':
19:28:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/range_access.h:68:5: error: 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'end'
 In constructor 'Cache::Cache(uint64_t)':
23:77: error: no matching function for call to 'std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>::unordered_map()'
23:77: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/unordered_map:48:0,
                 from 3:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:172:7: note: std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_map(std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>&&) [with _Key = Key; _Tp = int; _Hash = THash; _Pred = TEqual; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, int> >]
       unordered_map(unordered_map&&) = default;
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:172:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:169:7: note: std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_map(const std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>&) [with _Key = Key; _Tp = int; _Hash = THash; _Pred = TEqual; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, int> >]
       unordered_map(const unordered_map&) = default;
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:169:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
 In member function 'void Cache::Set(int32_t, int32_t)':
28:41: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Key'
5:8: error: forward declaration of 'struct Key'
29:34: error: 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'find'
34:41: error: 'Key lru' has incomplete type
35:42: error: 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'find'
36:41: error: 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'end'
36:57: error: 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'erase'
39:33: error: 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'end'
41:22: error: 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'erase'
45:18: error: 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'emplace'
 In member function 'int32_t Cache::Get(int32_t)':
52:41: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Key'
5:8: error: forward declaration of 'struct Key'
53:34: error: 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'find'
54:33: error: 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'end'
56:22: error: 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'erase'
58:22: error: 'class std::unordered_map<Key, int, THash, TEqual>' has no member named 'emplace'
```

Comment: What's the compiler error?

Comment: The problem I see is that you are using the class `Key` before you have defined it.

Comment: updated. @cigien

Comment: @john I just made that change, and brough the declarations on top. The code works fine. Whats wrong with forward declaration?

Comment: You have to declare your classes before you use them.  You can forward declare them and use them only for pointers and references and returns, but you need to have declared them for any other purpose before using them.

Comment: Your code compiles for me, if I move `Key`, `TEqual` and `THash` before the definition of `Cache`

Comment: @Eljay Which operation is breaking forward declaration operations?

Comment: [A question just like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61356085/5684257) came up a couple days ago. It's undefined behavior to instantiate `std::unordered_map` at an incomplete type. Easiest thing to do here seems to be just moving the definitions of your three classes up before `Cache`. It doesn't take any operation. You simply *cannot* define `Cache` before defining the other three classes, unless you change `Cache` to contain just a pointer to the map or something (which is not what anyone wants).

Comment: The one's that your error messages are pointing out.

Comment: @john I didn't know about this limitations of forward declarations. I think there will be many like me who might run into this problem. So I have rephrased this question and can accept your response as accepted, in case you can "Answer" it and get the credits.